# How to setup Wifi using the command-line?

Tags: wireless, command-line

How do I setup Wifi using the command line?

I need to setup as following, but its failed:

## Target:

```
Security: WEP
Network name: wifi59/7
Key/password: xyz
```

## Tried and failed:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode managed
sudo iwconfig wlan0 channel 11
sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid wifi59/7
sudo iwconfig wlan0 key xyz
Error for wireless request "Set Encode" (8B2A) :
    SET failed on device wlan0 ; Invalid argument.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The WEP key should be in hex, and either 10 or 26 characters long (5 or 13 ASCII bytes).

If you want to specify it in ASCII, you have to prefix it with `s:` - I'm not sure if iwconfig will pad out an ASCII password, but try lengths of 5 or 13.

See `man iwconfig` and scroll down to **`key/enc[ryption]`** for some examples.

Comment: Nobody can tell me why the s: option just never works. There's something wrong with the syntax, stack overflow has 3 open questions about this now, and none of them have been answered.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is easier and more reliable to use networkmanager's default command line utiliy called nm-cli. Please have a look at nm-cli to familiarize yourself with nm-cli syntax.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

```
$sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces

#The primary network interface
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
# wireless-* options are implemented by the wireless-tools package
wireless-mode managed
wireless-essid YOUR_SSID
wireless-key1 s:YOUR_PASS
address 192.168.1.200
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 200.48.225.130 200.48.225.146
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vim /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
```

and insert the following configuration stanza while replacing the SSID-NAME-HERE and PASSWORD-HERE with your SSID network name and password:

```
wifis:
    wlan0:
        optional: true
        access-points:
            "SSID-NAME-HERE":
                password: "PASSWORD-HERE"
        dhcp4: true
```

Make sure that the wifis block is aligned with the above ethernets or version block if present.

[Source](https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-20-04-connect-to-wifi-from-command-line)